# Error when running linear kernel ridge regression fitting on dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression

Trying to fit a linear kernel ridge regression model on a dataset with 8 features.

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request
url = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/concrete/compressive/Concrete_Data.xls'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, './Concrete_Data.xls')
data = pd.read_excel('./Concrete_Data.xls')
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

new_col_names = ["Cement", "BlastFurnaceSlag", "FlyAsh", "Water", "Superplasticizer","CoarseAggregate", "FineAggregate", "Age", "CC_Strength"]

curr_col_names = list(data.columns)

mapper = {}
for i,name in enumerate(curr_col_names):
  mapper[name] = new_col_names[i]

data = data.rename(columns=mapper)

X = data.iloc[:,:-1]
y = data.iloc[:,-1]
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=2)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()

x_train = sc.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test = sc.transform(x_test)
from sklearn.kernel_ridge import KernelRidge

kr = KernelRidge(alpha=1.0)
kr.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred_kr = kr.predict(y_test)
```

When I try to run the code, there is an error that says the expected array is meant to be 2D but is a 1D array. Could someone let me know what I am possibly doing wrong?

Comment: You have given `y_pred_kr = kr.predict(y_test)` instead of `y_pred_kr = kr.predict(x_test)`